# Is there a way to find all typeclasses of type in Template Haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

The question is in the title. Given a type, is there a way to find all the typeclasses it instantiates. I'm try to get the list of *fields* generated by `makeField` (`lens`).Example

```
 data Point = Point { _x :: Double, _y :: Double } deriving (Show).
```

I would like given `Point` to get `[HasX, HasY, Show]`.
Alternatively, is there a way to get all the `Name` in scope ?

Comment: Why would you need that? Just curious. You certainly can't find typeclasses defined in modules you don't import; as far as I can tell TH doesn't have any way to enumerate "whatever is visible from here".

Comment: I'm trying to automatically instanciate typeclass for sum types.

Comment: How would you instantiate e.g. a Monad for a sum type?

Comment: I'm only instantiating typeclasses following a certain pattern, not every typeclasses.